# How to match string starting with one of the two specified chars followed by two or more digits

Tags: c#, regex

- Matches : X23, A4858, A09387373, X90
- Non-matches : G23, X23H, A48B59, A48BA484646

I came up with the following,

```
var rex = new Regex(@"^([AX](\d\d)+)");
```

but this matches X23H, A48B59,A48BA484646

How do I make sure it's a string starting with either 'A' or 'X' and then followed by two or more digits?

Comment: is it `2^n` series?

Comment: Not necessarily, could be A124 etc

Comment: then check :- https://regex101.com/r/gQ2vY3/3

Comment: Ah interesting site, thanks. Seems to work.

Comment: its not specifically for c#..for c# regex you can use http://regexstorm.net/ or regexhero.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least `n` of some pattern can be accomplished by using `{n,}`. You probably also want to mark the end of the string. Try doing:

```
var rex = new Regex(@"^([AX]\d{2,})$");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing [end of line anchor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=vs.110).aspx) (`$`):

```
var rex = new Regex(@"^([AX](\d\d)+)$");
```

That's why your expression matches correctly in the beginning, but "grabs too much" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine...
It's taking 'A' or 'X' as First Character and followed by 2 digits.

```
var rex = new Regex(@"^[AX]{1}\d{2}$");
```

you can play with ^ and $ to best suit your requirement and also regexOptions.